# Import custom module from other directory

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

Let's say I have a custom module in:

```
/basexx_yy/subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/subdir4/custom_module.py
```

And the script which needs to import `custom_module.py`is located at:

```
/basexx_yy/subdir1/otherdir/script.py
```

The `basexx_yy` is a dir with a dynamic name, consider `xx` and `yy` to be time stamps, let's say for the sake of clarity that `xx` is day of the week (01 = Monday - 05 = Friday) and `yy` is week number (`subdir1` - `subdir4` are constant). So the full path to `custom_module.py` cannot be included as a static address. Since the subdirs are constant, I wrote the following code:

```
import os
import sys
cwd = os.getcwd()
split = cwd.split('\\')
if 'subdir1' in split:
    parentdir = cwd.split('subdir1')
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(parentdir[0], 'subdir1', 'subdir2', 'subdir3', 'subdir4'))
else:
    sys.exit("'subdir' dir not found! Run the script from within basedir.")

import custom_module
```

It does not, however, work. I'd appreciate some clarity as I cannot see why this doesn't work.

Comment: Is the whole thing a package and are `subdir*` modules? If not, why not?

Comment: Yes, `custom_module.py` is a custom made package that can be imported in Python (i have done it for scripts within the same dir as `custom_module`) `subdir*` are directories.

Comment: I don't think we are [talking about the same thing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html): `custom_module.py` being a package makes no sense. I would think `basexx_yy` is a package and all `subdir*` are modules (they contain an `__init__.py`).

Comment: Oh, my apologies, none of the directories listed here are modules. (none contain an `__init__.py` file | There is also no `setup.py` present in the file structure. Do I need to add those files? Will it work then if I add an empty `__init__.py` inside every directory @NilsWerner

Comment: You can import things if they are a package and inside your include path (`pip install`ed) or both are modules and inside the same module tree (`__init__.py` everywhere, even in `otherdir`).

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly clear from your question what your situation is, but here goes as it was *designed to be used*:

- A *package* contains a `setup.py` and can be installed using `pip`.
- A *module* lives inside a package or a module and contains an `__init__.py`.

Your package should have a structure like

```
setup.py
basexx_yy/
          __init__.py
          something_else.py
          subdir1/
                  __init__.py
                  more_files.py
                  otherdir/
                           script.py
                  subdir2/
                          __init__.py
                          etc.py
                          subdir3/
                                  __init__.py
                                  pp.py
                                  subdir4/
                                          __init__.py
                                          custom_module.py
```

`basexx_yy` being a package means it can be installed into your python library collection using

```
pip install basexx_yy
```

or, while developing

```
pip install -e basexx_yy
```

Afterwards any script (it may even be completely outside your package) can do

```
import basexx_yy
```

and also deep import like

```
import basexx_yy.subdir1.subdir2.subdir3.subdir4.custom_module as cm

cm.sqrt(4)
```

or, any file in your module tree (`otherdir` is missing `__init__.py` so it is outside the module tree and cannot do this) can do relative imports.

e.g. `custom_module.py` can do

```
from . import custom_modules
from .. import pp
from ... import etc
from .... import more_files
from ..... import something_else
```

Comment: Do I still need to create modules if I am using `sys.path.insert`? I have used this command before without having to go through these steps. @NilsWerner

Comment: The point is you shouldn't need to mess with `sys.path`. If you do you're already doing it wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nils Werner, that you most probably want to restructure your package(s).

Anyway, your code should work! Only problem is that you use

```
split = cwd.split('\\')
```

instead of

```
split = cwd.split(os.path.sep)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot restructure the files because there are many other scripts which use `custom_module`. The amount of work for just this error would be a nightmare. I can, however, put this script i am writing in the same directory as `custom_module` but i'd rather not until I know it's the only viable option.

Comment: Of course it's not the only viable option. Your example works! .... just not split by '\\' (unless you are on windows)